# Facebook SDK - Unity - Login to another Account after first Login?

Tags: account

Hi i´ve a qestion so i integrated the facebook sdk for unity and there when you login once it stores your logindatat somewhere i´dont know so you don´t have to login again each time if you want to play the game how this said
"This property might be true when SetInit is called if the API detects that the user has already previously authed the app in a previous session. This means the user doesn't have to click the login button every time they play the game."
But now i want to know how i can login into another account if i logged in once ... 
Thus i have to login the stored information which facebook sdk stores to login into an account.
Cause if i want to login after first time facebook don´t ask me to which account i want to login.
So there must be some "stored" playerprefs which i can overwrite so that the sdk thinks again thats must be the first login ? : /
Or isn´t that feasible ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to logout manually if you have the Facebook App installed on your device. Then you can login with another account from your app. Otherwise `FB.logout()` should work to logout if you don't have the FB App installed and you'll be able to login via some browser again.